# Icons from css files are not loading in flutter webview , showing box with X instead of icons

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am working on a wrapper app of flutter webview, using **flutter_inappwebview** plugin.

website url : https://remotewant.com/

Icons are loading in mobile browser (chrome) :
[image]

But Icons are not loading in flutter webview app , it is showing box with X instead of icons :

[image]

please provide suggestion to solve this.